# how to record workflow in SAP using SHDB?

Tags: automation, development-environment, sap-gui

I am currently working front end of SAP application  now i am going develop automation process using Excel VBA with BDC, But in my work place most of developing transaction access denied (SHDB, SE38). Is there any online or free sap application for practice BDC program and record.

Answer (score 1):

The only service, which provided test worldwide access to IDES, was Consolut, but recently it was [discontinued](https://www.consolut.com/en/s/sap-ides-access.html). However, you can buy live access to SAP system [directly from SAP](https://training.sap.com/shop/live-access), or request [SAP Sneak Preview (MiniSAP)](https://websmp130.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/minisap/minisap.htm), or try [pre-configured virtual appliances](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-41566) from SAP Cloud Appliance Library free of charge. However your question isn't really related to development area.